# cmd curl json to php script

Tags: php, json, curl, command-line

I am trying to POST json data from commandline with curl to a php script.
But I can't figure out how to receive the posted json on the Server site (php)

This is what I have tried so far:

commandline:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -i -d '{"token":"xyz"}' http://localhost/api/users.php
```

users.php

```
//Receive the RAW post data.
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $content;

// try to decode json
$decoded = json_decode($content);

if($decoded){ 
    echo "success";
    echo $decoded['token'];
}
else{
    echo "failed";
}
```

The result that I get is:

```
'{token:xyz}'
failed
```

I also tried to escape the " in the curl call like:

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -i -d '{\"token\":\"xyz\"}' http://localhost/api/users.php
```

but then I get almost the same result:

```
'{"token":"xyz"}'
failed
```

So my Problem is that the php script fails to convert the received json data.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT (Solved):**

Call cmd curl command with double quotes and escape quotes in between:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -i -d "{\"token\":\"xyz\"}" http://localhost/api/users.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems ok, but after testing your example it seems to be working only if i put double quotes around the post data. Try it.

Comment: perfect thank you! with double qoutes around and escaping the quotes in between worked :-) tried hours get this running...